# Slurm : srun with multiple executables

Tags: python, linux, distributed-computing, slurm, sbatch

Is there a way to have run commands run one after the other under a single `srun`? Additionally, can this be done without *srunning* a seperate file that has all the commands ?

Normally we would do :

```
srun python ./python_code.py
```

But I want :

```
srun python ./python_code1.py & python ./python_code2.py
```

Is this possible, or will it end up doing `srun python ./python_code1.py`, then `python ./python_code2.py` ?

Alternatively, I can have a file that contains my list of executables, like this :

`launch.sh:`

```
python ./python_code_1.py
python ./python_code_2.py
```

which I  would then call using `srun launch.sh`.

But I want to do this all from a single file, if possible.

Thank,

Liam

Comment: sooooo `srun sh -c 'python ./python_code_1.py ; python ./python_code_2.py'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line such as

```
srun python ./python_code1.py & python ./python_code2.py
```

will start `python ./python_code1.py` through `srun` and send that process to the background, and immediately start `python ./python_code2.py`.

As `srun` is expecting an executable, you cannot directly list multiple commands as arguments. But it will forward the arguments of the command so you can use an intermediate invocation of `bash` as suggested by @KamilKuk:

```
srun bash -c 'python ./python_code_1.py ; python ./python_code_2.py'
```

The alternative you mention with `launch.sh` will work provided `launch.sh` is executable, i.e. has the executable permission and has a proper [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works, but in the srun documentation, they say that you can write a list of executables. What do you know what they mean by that ? https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#SECTION_SYNOPSIS

Comment: That is for heterogeneous / MPMD jobs, you can specify different executables that will be started concurrently

Comment: Ok, I thought they would execute one after the other. Your original method is ideal for me. Thank you